# Custom Array Class: Constructor for Initialization of List

Tags: c++

I'm working on a custom array class in C++ (as a self-led exercise), and I'm not sure how to create a constructor that allows me to do something along the lines of:

```
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    array<int> test = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << test(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error that the compiler (VS Express 2013) gives me is "no instance of constructor array::array [with T = int]" matches the argument list. argument types are (int, int, int, int)."

I'm not sure what the constructor that takes the enumeration of a set of elements is called. I know I've properly overloaded `operator()(const int&)`. I also know that this (for a reason that's not clear to me) works:

```
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    array<char> test = "abcd";
    std::cout << test(1) << std:: endl; // prints 'a', as expected. 
    std::cout << test(4) << std::endl; // prints 'd', as expected.
    return 0;
}
```

This is achieved with a `array(const T[])` constructor: will the solution for the `array<int> test = {1, 2, 3, ..., n}` case be similar?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

**EDIT:** Including the code below, in case it's helpful.

```
template<typename T>
class array
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
private:
    iterator head;
    unsigned long elems;
public:
    array()
        : head(nullptr)
        , elems(0) {}
    array(const unsigned long &size)
        : head(size > 0 ? new T[size] : nullptr)
        , elems(size) {}
    array(const T[]);
    array(const array&);
    ~array() { delete[] head; }

    iterator begin() const { return head; }
    iterator end() const { return head != nullptr ? &head[elems] : nullptr; }
    unsigned long size() const { return elems; }

    array& operator=(const array&);
    T& operator()(const unsigned long&);
};

template<typename T>
array<T>::array(const T rhs[])
{
    unsigned long size = sizeof(rhs) / sizeof(T);
    head = new T[size];
    iterator pointer = begin();
    for (const_iterator i = &rhs[0]; i != &rhs[0] + size; i++)
        *pointer++ = *i;
}

template<typename T>
array<T>::array(const array<T> &rhs)
{
    head = new T[rhs.size()];
    iterator pointer = begin();
    for (const_iterator i = rhs.begin(); i != rhs.end(); i++)
        *pointer++ = *i;
}

template<typename T>
array<T>& array<T>::operator=(const array<T> &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        delete[] head;
        head = new T[rhs.size()];
        iterator pointer = begin();
        for (const_iterator i = rhs.begin(); i != rhs.end(); i++)
            *pointer++ = *i;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
T& array<T>::operator()(const unsigned long &index)
{
    if (index < 1 || index > size())
    {
        // Add some error-handling here.
    }
    return head[index - 1];
}
```

Comment: where is your `array class template` code?

Comment: That was a glaring omission on my part: apologies. I've included it above.

Comment: `sizeof(rhs)` in `array<T>::array(const T rhs[])` certainly isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: `warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'const char *' instead of 'const char []' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <initializer_list>

// ...

template <typename T>
class array
{   
    // ... 
    array(std::initializer_list<T> il);    

// ...    
template <typename T>
array<T>::array(std::initializer_list<T> il)
{
    unsigned long size = il.size();
    head = new T[size];
    iterator pointer = begin();
    for (const T& i : il)
        *pointer++ = i;
}

// ...
array<int> test = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d7ce48468f39faa)

---

*Suggested improvements:*

1. `array(const T rhs[]);` is an equivalent of `array(const T* rhs);`, that is, a pointer, which means that `sizeof(rhs) / sizeof(T)` expression will not give you the number of items. If you want a special constructor for `const char*`, then consider either an entire `array<char>` specialization or at least disabling this constructor from the overload resolution if `T` is not `char`
2. `head = new T[size];` default-initializes all elements (calls default constructor for each instance of type `T`). Then you call an assignment operation: `*pointer++ = *i;`. This can be improved by utilizing a *placement-new*, like `::new ((void*)ptr) T(*i);` where `ptr` is a pointer to a raw, uninitialized memory buffer, like `new char[sizeof(T)*size]` or returned from [`get_temporary_buffer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer).

---

And if you are wondering why the following works `array<char> test = { "abcd" };` with **your current** implementation then here is an explanation:

1. `array<T>` class has a constructor taking `const T[]`, which for `T=char` is instantiated as `array<char>::array(const char*)`.
2. *List-initialization* can be used to call object's constructor.
3. Your `const T[]` constructor is not explicit, which means that you can use *copy-initialization* syntax like below:

   ```
   array<char> test = { "test" };
   ```
4. The expression `sizeof(rhs) / sizeof(T)`, although not valid as explained above, for `T=char` evaluates to `sizeof(char*) / sizeof(char)`, which is (most-probably) `4 / 1 = 4`.
5. Your `"test"` used for initialization has exactly 4 letters, your luck.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer, Piotr. One question: how does `std::initializer_list<T>` know the number of arguments passed? Isn't it just a pair of pointers (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/initializer_list)? How are these pointers constructed given something like `{1, 2, 3, 4}`?

Comment: Its a compile time object, Compiler counts them,  use .size() member function to know how many are there.