# Pointers to First and Last Members: List Initialization

Tags: c++

Tangentially-related, follow-on beginner question to a question that I had originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391745/custom-array-class-constructor-for-initialization-of-list/26391928?noredirect=1#comment41438118_26391928).

In short: how (without using any of the standard library's containers) can I access the pointers of type `T` that point to the first and last element of a list-initialization? In case my explanation is not understandable:

`int x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

If I wanted to create a custom class `template<typename T> class array<T> {};` that I can list-initialize, it's my understanding that I could leverage `std::initializer_list` to be [able to do this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

My question is: how would I be able to replicate that behavior? It looks like it leverages [std::begin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin2) to do this, but (unless I'm mistaken) that still begs the question: how can I write code that says "return a pointer to the first element of a list to be allocated on the stack" and, at the same time, "return a pointer to the first-past-the-last element of a list to be allocated on the stack"?

I realize that there's a significant "reinventing-the-wheel" component to my question (i.e. why shouldn't I go ahead and use `std::initializer_list`), but I just want to make sure I understand what the standard library is doing.

Comment: I dont understand why do you want to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I don't understand what behavior you want to replicate. If you want to write your own `initializer_list`, that's not possible.

Comment: That was exactly what I was wondering, @AntonSavin: thank you. I'd be happy to accept your answer should you choose to post it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write your own `initializer_list`, that's not possible. By this I mean that you can't achieve the behavior where a line like this

```
array<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

would call a contructor like `array(my_custom_initializer_list)`.

This is because `std::initializer_list` is a special class which is explicitly mentioned in the C++ standard as the argument type for list-initialization.

The relevant quotes are spread all over the text, but the essential parts are:

#### 8.5.4/2 List-initialization:

> A constructor is an *initializer-list constructor* if its first parameter is of type `std::initializer_list<E>` or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_list<E>` for some type `E`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments

#### 13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the
> candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements
> of the initializer list.